# Remove the cookies if it changed on the browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies

Even if I use **HttpOnly cookie** I noticed that I can change the cookie from the browser.

And I store the users' tokens in the cookie,
so I don't want any user copy the token of another user, then he gets user authorization and data.

So I want to remove the cookies **to remove All-access**, if anyone has changed cookies in the browser.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Answer (score 0):

You should hash it and make it time sensitive.
There's no way you forbid user to view and manipulate cookies on their browser.

Comment: yes, I know that I can't forbid users to view and manipulate cookies on their browser. but I want to know if there someone has changed his cookies by his self, not from the system